# Solving second order differential equation [$\ddot{z} = \frac{-k}{m}v_z$]

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this second order equation $$\ddot{z} = \frac{-k}{m}v_z$$

I don't see how to solve this. I found few way to solve a second order equation, but I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Here's my latest attempt. I'll try to be as clear as possible, but to be honest I'm really confuse.

$$\frac{dv_z}{dt} = -\frac{k}{m} v_z$$
$$\int \frac{dv_zm}{-kv_z} = \int dt$$
$$\frac{-m}{k}ln|v_z| + C = t$$
$$\frac{m}{k} = \tau$$
$$v_z = e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}+c}$$

I'm stuck here.

The finale answer should be $$z(t) = z_0 + \tau V_{0z}[1 - e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}]$$
$z(t=0) = z_0 , v_z(t=0) = v_{0z}$

I hope what I did make a little sense.

Comment: Is it $\ddot{z} = -k \dot{z}/m$ or $\ddot{z} = -k v_{z} /m$? If it is the first, either guess the solution goes like $e^{\lambda t}$ for some $\lambda$ or multiply by $\dot{z}$ and use $z'z'' = (z'^{2})'/2$. If it is the latter, what is $v_{z}$ supposed to represent?

Comment: I fix it. It's $\ddot{z} = -\frac{k}{m} v_{0z}$

I get it from $m\ddot{z}= -kv_{0z}$

I thought $\dot{z} = v_z$, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an ordinary differential equation (ODE) which doesn't explicitly contain the independent variable (called autonomous) you've really got many options to solve it. Starting with your ODE
\begin{align}
\ddot z=-\frac{k}{m}\dot z,
\end{align}
I'll divide by $\dot z$ and integrate
\begin{align}
\int_0^{t}\left(\frac{\ddot z}{\dot z}+\frac{k}{m}\right)\mathrm dt'&=0\\
\ln\left(\frac{\dot z}{v_0}\right)+\frac{k}{m}(t-t_0)&=0,
\end{align}
solving for $\dot z$
\begin{align}
\dot z&=v_0e^{-\frac{k}{m}(t-t_0)}.
\end{align}
Integrating again,
\begin{align}
\int_0^t\dot z\mathrm dt'=\int_0^t v_0e^{-\frac{k}{m}(t'-t_0)}\mathrm dt'\\
z-z_0=-\frac{kv_0}{m}(1-e^{-\frac{k}{m}(t-t_0)}).
\end{align}
So $z$ is
\begin{align}
z(t)=z_0-\frac{kv_0}{m}(1-e^{-\frac{k}{m}(t-t_0)}).
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't know we have many options to solve it.

Only one thing I'm not sure to understand.

I don't see how $$\int_0^t \frac{\ddot{z}}{\dot{z}} => ln(\frac{\dot{z}}{v_0})$$

Comment: @RedDiamond The derivative of $\ln(u(t))=\frac{\dot u(t)}{u(t)}$. So the integral gives $\ln(\dot z)\Big|_0^t=\ln(\dot z)-\ln(\dot z_0)=\ln\left(\frac{\dot z}{\dot z_0}\right)$

Comment: @RedDiamond when I say there are many options I just mean many different techniques will can get you to the answer.